# Why isn't my Apache reverse proxy working to translate anchor HREF attributes when sent back to the client?

Tags: heroku, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have

```
# For blog
LoadModule proxy_html_module libexec/mod_proxy_html.so
LoadModule ssl_module libexec/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule xml2enc_module libexec/mod_xml2enc.so
SSLProxyEngine on
ProxyRequests off
ProxyPass /blog https://xxxx.wordpress.com
ProxyPassReverse /blog https://xxxx.wordpress.com
ProxyHTMLEnable On
ProxyHTMLURLMap https://xxxx.wordpress.com /blog
<Location /blog>
  ProxyPassReverse /
  ProxyHTMLEnable On
  ProxyHTMLURLMap / /blog
  RequestHeader    unset  Accept-Encoding
  #LogLevel proxy:debug
</Location>
```

Following these guides:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-php-settings#using-a-custom-application-level-apache-configuration

http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_proxy.html

When I visit the URL http://www.xxxx.com/blog/ it doesn't substitute anchor links https://xxxx.wordpress.com/2015/09/16/hello-world/ with /blog.

It works locally, but not in production.

Here is an example of the HTML that goes through the proxy and appears in the browser:

```
<h1 class="entry-title">
  <a href="https://xxxx.wordpress.com/2015/09/16/hello-world/" rel="bookmark">Hello world!</a></h1>
```

I also used a different blog host (HostGator) instead of Wordpress.com but it still doesn't work. (Not that this should matter.)

Apache 2.4.16, production: 2.4.10 (?)

Answer (score 0):

The links in the response body cant be updated with proxy reference unless  there is a feature in target host to return expected URLs or else you need to explicitly manage the links in the response body by additonal coding.
 [More Details..](https://serverfault.com/questions/561892/how-to-handle-relative-urls-correctly-with-a-reverse-proxy/)

If its working in dev means there is such config which you are missing in prod.

Comment: `ProxyHTMLURLMap` is specifically for that purpose of re-writing URLs in the HTML.