# Apache ProxyPass with links and content

Tags: apache-2.4, proxypass

I try proxypass "test" directory and all content with further links via apache config

`ProxyPass /test/ http://manobatai/`

ProxyPass works and it could be fine, but when i click on link i get that URL not found.

Comment: Have you tried to add also `ProxyPassReverse "/test/" "http:/ /manobatai/"`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i just tried but i get same result, so i think that i need regex with ProxyPassMatch directive.

Comment: ProxyPass does not change the (HTML) content of the responses  that are proxied, so an absolute link to `http://manobatai/dir/page.html` or   `/dir/page.html`  won't get converted to `http://example.com/test/dir/page.html` Please see [this answer of mine here](http://serverfault.com/a/561897/37681)