# proxy redirect to wrong url when not redirect to /

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, apache2

I have read many similar issues with many solutions to this issue but how ever I try I fail.

The issue:
I have a apache2 installed at debian 9(tried nginx but has the same issue). I use thise configurations:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ProxyPreserveHost On
 ProxyPass /nas/ http://[IP]:[port]/
 ProxyPassReverse /nas/ http://[IP]:[port]/
```

With this configurations I reach "http://[IP]/redirect.html" when browsing the proxy IP and a white page with black text "Not Found"

So, If I add

```
ProxyPass /redirect.html http://[IP]:[port]/redirect.html
ProxyPassReverse /redirect.html http://[IP]:[port]/redirect.html
```

I still get the "Not Found" page but the url is searching for http://[IP]/cgi-bin

Adding:

```
ProxyPass /cgi-bin/ http://[IP]:[port]/cgi-bin/
ProxyPassReverse /cgi-bin/ http://[IP]:[port]/cgi-bin/
```

I reach my site, however, nothing works, the language has been change of all the buttons and it does not happens anything when I press the links.

Now, I figured out that this stupied qnap nas I try to redirect my clients to redirect all the java and css to / or something like that (note that I'm do not have much knowledge about webpages and how they work so sorry for not using the right words)

If I use ProxyPass / instead of ProxyPass /nas/ it works fine but I do want to use http://[IP]/ for another webpage than the nas so I'm not satisfied.

When searching for the issue I got the answer that I should change the nas to redirect all traffic to the proxy address instead but however I try the qnap is not very easy to handel and I'm still no webdesigner so I do not know what to change and all that. I thought about installing freenas instead but I want that to be my last solution since it will be very much work for me.

So, do anyone know if there is a easy quick fix to my issue?
And as I said, I have tried nginx also with different kind of headers without luck and with that said I want u to know I don't mind to try another kind off proxy application if apache do not have what I need.

Comment: The problem with reverse proxies is frequently that the back-end doesn't play nice and loads content from a (large) number of different absolute paths. I have described some strategies in [this Q&A](https://serverfault.com/q/561892/37681). The simplest is rather than addressing your webserver from your external ip-address with the ip-address, assign domain names and `www.example.com` can be a virtualhost with your website, `nas.example.com` can be second virtualhost where you can `ProxyPass /`

Comment: Thank you very much, I still use ip instead of changing to domain names but I added another virtualhost and now it works perfect.