# How to handle relative urls correctly with a nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, proxypass

Sure I'm not the first one that tried to serve a domain `example.com` from a `example.net/bbb`, but I haven't found a solution yet.

My NGINX configuration follows the [guidelines](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/) and looks something like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.net;
    root /path/to/aaa;

    location /bbb/ {
        proxy_pass http://example.com/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    location ~ \.(svg|ttf|js|css|svgz|eot|otf|woff|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico)$ {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        expires max;
    }
}
```

I can manage to render the root of `example.com` in `example.net/bbb` but:

#### ISSUE 1

`example.net/bbb/some/path` doesn't work as expected and the `index.html` of `example.net` is rendered.

#### ISSUE 2

Any asset in `example.com/assets` gives 404 because the browser look for `example.net/assets`. Be great if I could solve this without placing absolute paths everywhere.

Comment: Are both domains pointing at the same instance of Nginx?

Comment: They are currently on the same server if it's that what you mean by being on the same Nginx instance. But it'd be great to find a solution that works even if they are on two separate servers.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The problem is basically that using a `proxy_pass` directive won't rewrite HTML code and therefor relative URL's to for instance a `img src="/assets/image.png"` won't magically change to `img src="/bbb/assets/image.png"`.

I wrote about 
potential strategies to address that in Apache httpd [here](https://serverfault.com/a/561897/37681) and similar solutions are possible  for nginx as well:

- If you have control over `example.com` and the how the application/content is deployed there, **deploy in the same base URI** you want to use on example.net for the reverse proxy
  --> deploy your code in  `example.com/bbb` and then your `proxy_pass` will become quite an easy as /assets/image.png will have been  moved to /bbb/assets/image.png:

  ```
  location /bbb/ {
       proxy_pass http://example.com/bbb/;
  ```
- If you have control over `example.com` and the how the application/content is deployed:
  change to **relative paths**, i.e. rather than `img src="/assets/image.png"`
  refer to `img src="./assets/image.png"` from a page `example.com/index.html`
  and to `img src="../../assets/image.png"`from a page `example.com/some/path/index.html`
- Maybe you're lucky and example.com only uses **a few URI paths in the root** and non of those are used by example.net, then simply **reverse proxy every necessary subdirectory**:

  ```
  location /bbb/ {
       proxy_pass http://example.com/; 
  }
  location /assets/ {
       proxy_pass http://example.com/assets/; 
  }
  location /styles/ {
       proxy_pass http://example.com/styles/;
  ```
- give up using a  example.com as subdirectory on example.net and instead host it on a **subdomain of example.net**:

  ```
  server { 
    server_name bbb.example.net 
    location / {
       proxy_pass http://example.com/; 
    }
  }
  ```
- **rewrite the (HTML) content** by enabling the nginx [ngx_http_sub_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html). That will also allow you to rewrite absolute URL's  with something similar to:

  ```
  location /bbb/ {
       sub_filter 'src="/assets/'  'src="/bbb/assets/';
       sub_filter 'src="http://example.com/js/' 'src="http://www.example.net/bbb/js/' ;
       sub_filter_once off;
       proxy_pass http://example.com/; 
  }
  ```

Comment: I can definitely do the first option. The last one is pretty extreme but it's good to know there's such an alternative.

Comment: Excellent explanation of the implementation options. I've been looking for a breakdown like this for quite some time, happy I finally found it. Thank you.

Comment: The "rewrite the (HTML) content" solution is exactly what is needed when you have to deal with some dockerized service that you cannot modify! Thanks a lot, it was so easy!

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason why the index page cannot correctly jump to sub-folder like `\bbb` is this line in html file: `<base href="/">`, which means it will throw off any existing folder whenever jump to a new path.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to subdir's html file for default index.html. for example, copy /main/mainView.html to /index.html and use base tag in index.html to set relative location's base path.

*I think adjusting client page's relative location's base path can be modified by not server-side but client-side(browser). because the page(client-side asset) has no way to know its real location in server-side.

Answer (score 0):

I had issues like you , If i have two container , each of them load a different frontend app , you should change a base root url for each your project in html for example :

```
<base target="_blank" href="http://localhost:8081/react-app/" />
```

this is in another container , but main project is on 80 , so it can find style files and etc .
and for change a base route for child route i found sth for react router as name basename that can set

Answer (score 0):

Since the homepage already redirects you to the path "/admin/", the correct approach would be to check the path and issue a "return 302" to adjust the "location" as it appears in the original URL. See the examples below.

##### Nginx version

```
Docker: nginx:1.25-alpine3.18
Nginx: 1.25
```

#### Original URL:

http://192.168.29.2:8088/admin/

#### Reverse proxy:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name ~^(dns).youdomain.com;

    client_max_body_size 50M;
    include ssl_config.config;

    location = / {
        return 302 https://$host/admin/;
    }

    location /admin/ {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.29.2:8088/admin/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

#### ssl_config.config

```
    # SSL configuration
    ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/certs/certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/certs/certificate.key;

    #ssl_protocols TLSv1.3 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    resolver_timeout 5s;
    add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";

    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/certs/dhparam.pem;

    # Your server DNS here
    resolver 192.168.29.2;
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/562340)