# Force browser requests to respect rewritten path in nginx

Tags: nginx

I've set up nginx as a back proxy. This back proxy rewrites the path of `https://<my-domain>/artifactory` to `http://127.0.0.1:8082` essentially stripping off the path. This works on the first request, but when the browser loads the index.html, that file mentions a bunch of assets with relative paths like `/ui/css/app.c2d4f448.css`. When the browser is requesting them from the server it is requesting with `http://<my-domain>/ui/css/app.c2d4f448.css` instead of with the /artifactory path. Is there any way to instruct the browser to append a path to the host before making it's requests, via headers or something?

Comment: Read [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/932628/how-to-handle-relative-urls-correctly-with-a-nginx-reverse-proxy) Q/A.

Comment: Thanks @IvanShatsky not sure why the site didn't show that near exact duplicate when I was searching for it. Ty, closing question