# Nginx - Reverse proxy serving ScreenConnect does not prepend subdirectory

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, directory

I am running an unsecured ScreenConnect web interface on a machine on my local network. I would like to serve it through port 443 using nginx's reverse proxy, and access it via:

`https://<WAN.IP.ADDRESS>/screenconnect`

My nginx.conf location block:

```
            location / {
            root /www/var/nginx/html
            }

            location /screenconnect/ {
            proxy_pass                              http://local.screenconnect.server:8040/;
            proxy_buffering                         off;
            proxy_set_header Host                   $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP              $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For        $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto      $scheme;
            }
```

I am successful in getting to the Screen Connect Web Interface, and the url reads as 
`https://<WAN.IP.ADDRESS>/screenconnect/`

However, any additional subdirectories that I access, such as `https://<WAN.IP.ADDRESS>/screenconnect/login.php?` will drop the `/screenconnect/` subdirectory and try to access `https://<WAN.IP.ADDRESS>/login.php?` 
This throws me a 404 error.

**Things I've tried**

- I've inserted `/screenconnect/` to `https://<WAN.IP.ADDRESS>/login.php?/` and got `https://<WAN.IP.ADDRESS>/screenconnect/login.php?`, which gives me the site I need.
- I've adjusted the web.config file on my screenconnect server and appended the correct directory: 
  `<add key="WebServerAddressableUri" value="https://WAN.IP.ADDRESS:443/screenconnect/" />`
- I've tried removing the `/` at the end of `proxy_pass    http://local.screenconnect.server:8040/;` and `location /screenconnect/`
- I've also tried a host of different simple directives for the location block from people who have had related problems
- I've replaced the IP of the screenconnect server with an apache server running on port 80 that has a simple html page, which redirects to a subfolder. When redirecting, the /screenconnect/ directory is prepended correctly.

Comment: I believe that the application is doing this behavior due a miss or wrong configuration. I'm unfamiliar with rewrite of nginx but it might have a chance

Comment: Generally it is the ScreenConnect (or any upstream web app) job, to generate its links including the correct URI prefix. The only available info about this subject I found so far is [about](https://kimconnect.com/screenconnect-and-nginx/) the `WebServerAddressableUri` parameter which you already tried to adjust with no luck; unfortunally looks like the support forums are dead now. You can check the [How to handle relative urls correctly with a nginx reverse proxy](https://serverfault.com/questions/932628/how-to-handle-relative-urls-correctly-with-a-nginx-reverse-proxy) ServerFault thread.