# Serve multiple apps with nginx proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, proxypass

I'm trying to use a basic nginx reverse proxy to access three different apps, each running inside a docker container. The nginx reverse proxy is served on `http://127.0.0.1:8080` and i want to have the following behavior:

- `http://127.0.0.1:8080/api` route to Django backend api `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api`
- `http://127.0.0.1:8080/` route to the the main react app running on `http://127.0.0.1:5200`
- `http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2` route to a second app running on `http://127.0.0.1:5300`

This is the `nginx.conf`

```
events {}
http { 
    server {
        listen 8080;
        server_name 127.0.0.1;
        rewrite_log on;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
        # debug with cache off
        add_header Cache-Control no-cache;


        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5200;
            proxy_set_header  Host 127.0.0.1:5200;
        }
        location /api {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
            proxy_set_header  Host 127.0.0.1:8000;
        }
        location = /app2 {
            return 302 /app2/;
        }
        location /app2/ {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5300/;
            proxy_set_header  Host 127.0.0.1:5300;
        }
        if ($http_referer ~ https?://[^/]+/app2/(.*))
        {
            # rewrite request URI only if it isn't already started with '/app2' prefix
            rewrite ^((?!/app2).*) /app2$1;
        }
              
    }
}
```

If I use these routes in the second app, the `http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2` does not load the page and I get the below logs from nginx reverse proxy

```
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<Comp />} />
                <Route path="/test" element={<Comp2 />} />
            </Routes>             
        </BrowserRouter>
```

```
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2023:22:47:25 +0000] "GET /app2 HTTP/1.1" 302 145 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2023:22:47:25 +0000] "GET /app2/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1052 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2023/09/16 22:47:25 [warn] 29#29: *1 an upstream response is buffered to a temporary file /var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp/1/00/0000000001 while reading upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /app2/main.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5300/main.js", host: "127.0.0.1:8080", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/"
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2023:22:47:25 +0000] "GET /app2/main.js HTTP/1.1" 200 9778028 "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

I added a catch all route to the second app for test

```
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<Comp2 />} />
                <Route path="/aaa" element={<Comp2 />} />
                <Route path="/bbb" element={<Comp />} />
                <Route path="*" element={<Comp />} />
            </Routes>             
        </BrowserRouter>
```

This time, the page loads but all paths of app2 are showing `Comp`, the catch all rule is taking precedence. This is when I try to access through the reverse proxy`http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2`, but when accessing the second app directly on it's server `http://127.0.0.1:5300`, the paths loads the correct component

This is logs from 1/ reverse proxy and 2/ app2 nginx server, when hitting `http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2`
1/ nginx reverse proxy

```
2023/09/22 06:19:32 [notice] 29#29: *12 "https?://[^/]+/app2/(.*)" does not match "", client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /app2/ HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8080"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Sep/2023:06:19:32 +0000] "GET /app2/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1051 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2023/09/22 06:19:32 [notice] 29#29: *12 "https?://[^/]+/app2/(.*)" matches "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/", client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /app2/main.js HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8080", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/"
2023/09/22 06:19:32 [notice] 29#29: *12 "^((?!/app2).*)" does not match "/app2/main.js", client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /app2/main.js HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8080", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/"
2023/09/22 06:19:32 [warn] 29#29: *12 an upstream response is buffered to a temporary file /var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp/2/00/0000000002 while reading upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /app2/main.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5300/main.js", host: "127.0.0.1:8080", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Sep/2023:06:19:32 +0000] "GET /app2/main.js HTTP/1.1" 200 9875574 "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2023/09/22 06:19:33 [notice] 29#29: *12 "https?://[^/]+/app2/(.*)" matches "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/", client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /assets/img/faces/face_1.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8080", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/"
2023/09/22 06:19:33 [notice] 29#29: *12 "^((?!/app2).*)" matches "/assets/img/faces/face_1.jpg", client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /assets/img/faces/face_1.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8080", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/"
2023/09/22 06:19:33 [notice] 29#29: *12 rewritten data: "/app2/assets/img/faces/face_1.jpg", args: "", client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /assets/img/faces/face_1.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8080", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/"
2023/09/22 06:19:33 [notice] 29#29: *11 "https?://[^/]+/app2/(.*)" matches "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/", client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /assets/img/faces/face_4.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8080", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/"
2023/09/22 06:19:33 [notice] 29#29: *11 "^((?!/app2).*)" matches "/assets/img/faces/face_4.jpg", client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /assets/img/faces/face_4.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8080", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/"
2023/09/22 06:19:33 [notice] 29#29: *11 rewritten data: "/app2/assets/img/faces/face_4.jpg", args: "", client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /assets/img/faces/face_4.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8080", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Sep/2023:06:19:33 +0000] "GET /assets/img/faces/face_1.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 64369 "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2023/09/22 06:19:33 [notice] 29#29: *1 "https?://[^/]+/app2/(.*)" matches "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/", client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /assets/img/faces/face_3.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8080", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/"
2023/09/22 06:19:33 [notice] 29#29: *1 "^((?!/app2).*)" matches "/assets/img/faces/face_3.jpg", client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /assets/img/faces/face_3.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8080", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/"
2023/09/22 06:19:33 [notice] 29#29: *1 rewritten data: "/app2/assets/img/faces/face_3.jpg", args: "", client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /assets/img/faces/face_3.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8080", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Sep/2023:06:19:33 +0000] "GET /assets/img/faces/face_4.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 56227 "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2023/09/22 06:19:33 [notice] 29#29: *12 "https?://[^/]+/app2/(.*)" matches "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/", client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /assets/img/faces/face_5.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8080", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/"
2023/09/22 06:19:33 [notice] 29#29: *12 "^((?!/app2).*)" matches "/assets/img/faces/face_5.jpg", client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /assets/img/faces/face_5.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8080", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/"
2023/09/22 06:19:33 [notice] 29#29: *12 rewritten data: "/app2/assets/img/faces/face_5.jpg", args: "", client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /assets/img/faces/face_5.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8080", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Sep/2023:06:19:33 +0000] "GET /assets/img/faces/face_3.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 59833 "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2023/09/22 06:19:33 [notice] 29#29: *10 "https?://[^/]+/app2/(.*)" matches "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/", client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /assets/img/faces/face_6.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8080", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/"
2023/09/22 06:19:33 [notice] 29#29: *10 "^((?!/app2).*)" matches "/assets/img/faces/face_6.jpg", client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /assets/img/faces/face_6.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8080", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/"
2023/09/22 06:19:33 [notice] 29#29: *10 rewritten data: "/app2/assets/img/faces/face_6.jpg", args: "", client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /assets/img/faces/face_6.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8080", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/"
2023/09/22 06:19:33 [notice] 29#29: *1 "https?://[^/]+/app2/(.*)" matches "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/", client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /assets/img/faces/face_2.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8080", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/"
2023/09/22 06:19:33 [notice] 29#29: *1 "^((?!/app2).*)" matches "/assets/img/faces/face_2.jpg", client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /assets/img/faces/face_2.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8080", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/"
2023/09/22 06:19:33 [notice] 29#29: *1 rewritten data: "/app2/assets/img/faces/face_2.jpg", args: "", client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /assets/img/faces/face_2.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8080", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Sep/2023:06:19:33 +0000] "GET /assets/img/faces/face_5.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 66106 "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Sep/2023:06:19:33 +0000] "GET /assets/img/faces/face_6.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 60971 "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Sep/2023:06:19:33 +0000] "GET /assets/img/faces/face_2.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 80120 "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2023/09/22 06:19:33 [notice] 29#29: *10 "https?://[^/]+/app2/(.*)" matches "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/", client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /assets/css/fonts/Font-Awesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0 HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8080", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/"
2023/09/22 06:19:33 [notice] 29#29: *10 "^((?!/app2).*)" matches "/assets/css/fonts/Font-Awesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff2", client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /assets/css/fonts/Font-Awesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0 HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8080", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/"
2023/09/22 06:19:33 [notice] 29#29: *10 rewritten data: "/app2/assets/css/fonts/Font-Awesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff2", args: "v=4.7.0", client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /assets/css/fonts/Font-Awesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0 HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8080", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Sep/2023:06:19:33 +0000] "GET /assets/css/fonts/Font-Awesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0 HTTP/1.1" 200 77160 "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2023/09/22 06:19:33 [notice] 29#29: *12 "https?://[^/]+/app2/(.*)" matches "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/", client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /assets/css/fonts/Pe-Icon-Stroke/Pe-icon-7-stroke.woff?d7yf1v HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8080", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/"
2023/09/22 06:19:33 [notice] 29#29: *12 "^((?!/app2).*)" matches "/assets/css/fonts/Pe-Icon-Stroke/Pe-icon-7-stroke.woff", client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /assets/css/fonts/Pe-Icon-Stroke/Pe-icon-7-stroke.woff?d7yf1v HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8080", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/"
2023/09/22 06:19:33 [notice] 29#29: *12 rewritten data: "/app2/assets/css/fonts/Pe-Icon-Stroke/Pe-icon-7-stroke.woff", args: "d7yf1v", client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /assets/css/fonts/Pe-Icon-Stroke/Pe-icon-7-stroke.woff?d7yf1v HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8080", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Sep/2023:06:19:33 +0000] "GET /assets/css/fonts/Pe-Icon-Stroke/Pe-icon-7-stroke.woff?d7yf1v HTTP/1.1" 200 58556 "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2023/09/22 06:19:33 [notice] 29#29: *1 "https?://[^/]+/app2/(.*)" matches "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/", client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /assets/img/header-1.jpeg HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8080", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/"
2023/09/22 06:19:33 [notice] 29#29: *1 "^((?!/app2).*)" matches "/assets/img/header-1.jpeg", client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /assets/img/header-1.jpeg HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8080", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/"
2023/09/22 06:19:33 [notice] 29#29: *1 rewritten data: "/app2/assets/img/header-1.jpeg", args: "", client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /assets/img/header-1.jpeg HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8080", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Sep/2023:06:19:33 +0000] "GET /assets/img/header-1.jpeg HTTP/1.1" 200 430070 "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2023/09/22 06:19:33 [notice] 29#29: *11 "https?://[^/]+/app2/(.*)" matches "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/", client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /assets/img/header-2.jpeg HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8080", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/"
2023/09/22 06:19:33 [notice] 29#29: *11 "^((?!/app2).*)" matches "/assets/img/header-2.jpeg", client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /assets/img/header-2.jpeg HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8080", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/"
2023/09/22 06:19:33 [notice] 29#29: *11 rewritten data: "/app2/assets/img/header-2.jpeg", args: "", client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /assets/img/header-2.jpeg HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8080", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Sep/2023:06:19:33 +0000] "GET /assets/img/header-2.jpeg HTTP/1.1" 200 238167 "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2023/09/22 06:19:33 [notice] 29#29: *10 "https?://[^/]+/app2/(.*)" matches "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/", client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /assets/img/office-1.jpeg HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8080", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/"
2023/09/22 06:19:33 [notice] 29#29: *10 "^((?!/app2).*)" matches "/assets/img/office-1.jpeg", client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /assets/img/office-1.jpeg HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8080", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/"
2023/09/22 06:19:33 [notice] 29#29: *10 rewritten data: "/app2/assets/img/office-1.jpeg", args: "", client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /assets/img/office-1.jpeg HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8080", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Sep/2023:06:19:33 +0000] "GET /assets/img/office-1.jpeg HTTP/1.1" 200 383149 "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2023/09/22 06:19:34 [notice] 29#29: *10 "https?://[^/]+/app2/(.*)" matches "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/", client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /app2/favicon.png HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8080", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/"
2023/09/22 06:19:34 [notice] 29#29: *10 "^((?!/app2).*)" does not match "/app2/favicon.png", client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /app2/favicon.png HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8080", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Sep/2023:06:19:34 +0000] "GET /app2/favicon.png HTTP/1.1" 200 143748 "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2023/09/22 06:19:34 [notice] 29#29: *10 "https?://[^/]+/app2/(.*)" matches "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/", client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /static/assets/img/favicon.png HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8080", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/"
2023/09/22 06:19:34 [notice] 29#29: *10 "^((?!/app2).*)" matches "/static/assets/img/favicon.png", client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /static/assets/img/favicon.png HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8080", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/"
2023/09/22 06:19:34 [notice] 29#29: *10 rewritten data: "/app2/static/assets/img/favicon.png", args: "", client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /static/assets/img/favicon.png HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8080", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Sep/2023:06:19:34 +0000] "GET /static/assets/img/favicon.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1051 "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

2/ nginx server of app2

```
172.17.0.1 - - [22/Sep/2023:06:19:32 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 1051 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
172.17.0.1 - - [22/Sep/2023:06:19:32 +0000] "GET /main.js HTTP/1.0" 200 9875574 "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
172.17.0.1 - - [22/Sep/2023:06:19:33 +0000] "GET /assets/img/faces/face_1.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 64369 "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
172.17.0.1 - - [22/Sep/2023:06:19:33 +0000] "GET /assets/img/faces/face_4.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 56227 "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
172.17.0.1 - - [22/Sep/2023:06:19:33 +0000] "GET /assets/img/faces/face_3.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 59833 "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
172.17.0.1 - - [22/Sep/2023:06:19:33 +0000] "GET /assets/img/faces/face_5.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 66106 "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
172.17.0.1 - - [22/Sep/2023:06:19:33 +0000] "GET /assets/img/faces/face_6.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 60971 "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
172.17.0.1 - - [22/Sep/2023:06:19:33 +0000] "GET /assets/img/faces/face_2.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 80120 "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
172.17.0.1 - - [22/Sep/2023:06:19:33 +0000] "GET /assets/css/fonts/Font-Awesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0 HTTP/1.0" 200 77160 "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
172.17.0.1 - - [22/Sep/2023:06:19:33 +0000] "GET /assets/css/fonts/Pe-Icon-Stroke/Pe-icon-7-stroke.woff?d7yf1v HTTP/1.0" 200 58556 "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
172.17.0.1 - - [22/Sep/2023:06:19:33 +0000] "GET /assets/img/header-1.jpeg HTTP/1.0" 200 430070 "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
172.17.0.1 - - [22/Sep/2023:06:19:33 +0000] "GET /assets/img/header-2.jpeg HTTP/1.0" 200 238167 "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
172.17.0.1 - - [22/Sep/2023:06:19:33 +0000] "GET /assets/img/office-1.jpeg HTTP/1.0" 200 383149 "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
172.17.0.1 - - [22/Sep/2023:06:19:34 +0000] "GET /favicon.png HTTP/1.0" 200 143748 "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
172.17.0.1 - - [22/Sep/2023:06:19:34 +0000] "GET /static/assets/img/favicon.png HTTP/1.0" 200 1051 "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

I tried also to use rewrite for nginx (and with many diff regex) but got similar errors

```
        location /app2/ {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5300/;
            proxy_set_header  Host 127.0.0.1:5300; 
            rewrite ^/app2/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        }
```

How to configure nginx reverse proxy to remove `/app2` from the path and return the right page from the target app.

Comment: The general problem with a reverse proxy is that `proxy_pass` does not change HTML and other content. If for example a client requests `/app2/index.html`  and the HTML code your app2 generates has an `<img src="/assets/face_2.jpg"` that won't be changed to `<img src="/app2/assets/face_2.jpg"` by `proxy_pass` . And when the site visitor then requests `/assets/face_2.jpg` that goes to your main site (and probably is not found there resulting in a 404 error). I'll link to longer older answer thatis more generic than  [Geralds React specific answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1144241/37681)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle relative urls correctly with a nginx reverse proxy](https://serverfault.com/questions/932628/how-to-handle-relative-urls-correctly-with-a-nginx-reverse-proxy)

Comment: Nevertheless, rewriting the HTML at the proxy should always be a last resort. Every framework provides a way to configure the base URL.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I actually don't have issues with assets. The assets of app2 are loading correctly. More details in https://serverfault.com/questions/1143929/target-app-assets-not-loaded-with-nginx-proxy-pass.
The only issue with the nginx.conf I shared is that routing inside the apps is not working. Every path is loading the catch all route, and when I it remove, the page does not load at all.

Comment: Well,  then it is completely unclear to me what your actual problem is.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not clear. With the nginx.conf I shared, I don't see an issue  loading images & fonts (this has been fixed by https://serverfault.com/questions/1143929/target-app-assets-not-loaded-with-nginx-proxy-pass). 
The issue is that all paths `/app2`,  `/app2/aaa`, and `/app2/bbb`, are showing the same react component  `Comp`, as if all paths are handled by the catch all route. If I remove the catch all route, noting loads in browser.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured out what you are trying to solve.

When you request a page from `/app2/` it tries to load additional resources like `/main.js`, which results in a 404 error because it should be `/app2/main.js` instead.

If this is your problem you are trying an extremely complicated and unnecessary approach to fix it.

I'm further assuming the second app is also a React app, like the first. If this is the case you only need to [configure the base url of your app correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70299380/how-to-change-base-url-of-create-react-app).

> In your `package.json` file change the `homepage` entry to a relative path, excluding any sub-domain/nested directory.

In your case that would be:

```json
{
  ...,
  "homepage": "/app2/",
  ...
}
```

Then, the only thing you need in your nginx config would be:

```
        location /app2/ {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5300/;
            ### I don't think the Host header is even necessary
            # proxy_set_header  Host 127.0.0.1:5300;
        }
```

Your React app should now generate the correct URL for the reverse proxy automatically.

Comment: I added `"homepage": "/app2/"` to package.json, but it didn't work. I'm not sure if I'm missing something
What I noticed: when adding catch all route `<Route path="*" .. />` to app2,  I see `main.js` in browser sources. Removing this route, `main.js` is missing from browser.

Comment: and reverse proxy log when not using the catch all route has this WARN just before the `GET /app2/main.js` call
```
2023/09/23 19:02:55 [warn] 29#29: *291 an upstream response is buffered to a temporary file /var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp/2/01/0000000012 while reading upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /app2/main.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5300/main.js", host: "127.0.0.1:8080", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/"
```