# Target app assets not loaded with nginx proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, rewrite, proxypass

I have a basic nginx proxy running on `http://127.0.0.1:8080`.

This is the `nginx.conf`:

```
events {}
http { 
    server {
        listen 8080;
        server_name 127.0.0.1;
        rewrite_log on;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;


        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5200;
            proxy_set_header  Host 127.0.0.1:5200;
        }
        location /api {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
            proxy_set_header  Host 127.0.0.1:8000;
        }
        location = /app2 {
            return 302 /app2/;
        }
        location /app2/ {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5300/;
            proxy_set_header  Host 127.0.0.1:5300; 
        }

    }
}
```

When hitting `http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2`, the app running on port `5300` is displayed but the assets are not loaded correctly. I suspected nginx is proxying the request for the assets to the other app running on port `5200`, which is `location /` . I stopped this app to confirm and this is the log from nginx (note that upstream is shown as `http://127.0.0.1:5200...` but it should be `http://127.0.0.1:5300...`)

```
2023/09/17 23:47:32 [error] 29#29: *10 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /assets/css/fonts/Pe-Icon-Stroke/Pe-icon-7-stroke..ttf?d7yf1v HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5200/assets/css/fonts/Pe-Icon-Stroke/Pe-icon-7-stroke..ttf?d7yf1v", host: "127.0.0.1:8080", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/"
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Sep/2023:23:47:32 +0000] "GET /assets/css/fonts/Pe-Icon-Stroke/Pe-icon-7-stroke..ttf?d7yf1v HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2023/09/17 23:47:32 [error] 29#29: *10 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /assets/css/fonts/Font-Awesome/fontawesome-webfont..ttf?v=4.7.0 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5200/assets/css/fonts/Font-Awesome/fontawesome-webfont..ttf?v=4.7.0", host: "127.0.0.1:8080", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/"
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Sep/2023:23:47:32 +0000] "GET /assets/css/fonts/Font-Awesome/fontawesome-webfont..ttf?v=4.7.0 HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

Errors from console:
[image: Errors from console]

I see similar issue for `http://127.0.0.1:8080/api`, assets not loaded.
I tried rewrite rules with diff regex combinations as well, but got similar errors.

How to configure nginx to route to different apps and load their assets correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further digging and testing, the `rewrite` solution detailed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62836801/nginx-reverse-proxy-how-to-serve-multiple-apps worked in my case.

This is the snippet I added to my nginx.conf to get assets of app2 load correctly

```
if ($http_referer ~ https?://[^/]+/app2/(.*))
{
    # rewrite request URI only if it isn't already started with '/app2' prefix
    rewrite ^((?!/app2).*) /app2$1;
}
```