# apache reverse proxy - remove domain

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, rewrite

I want my virtualhost "new_target.domain.com" to point via apache reverse proxy to "https://target.com". This works fine but on new_target.domain.com the `a hrefs` are not correct. They point to https://target.com instead of new_target.domain.com.

**"https://target.com/videos/" instead of "https://new_target.domain.com/videos/" or "/videos/"**

How is it possible that I remove all the https://target.com references from all URLs so that there only remains "/videos/" in the source files?

Thanks, a lot.

Comment: The "problem" is that Apache mod_proxy `proxy_pass_reverse` only rewrite's HTTP protocol headers and not the **HTML** response bodies it receives from the upstream server. To rewrite the HTML pages themselves you need something such as http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_html.html - See for instance https://serverfault.com/a/634923/37681 for a solution

Comment: I also tried it with ProxyHTMLURLMap, but it also does not work correctly.

Comment: This solved my problem: ProxyHTMLEnable On
SetOutputFilter INFLATE;proxy-html;DEFLATE
ProxyHTMLURLMap <URL> / But for medium.com it does not work - they check if the request comes through a reverse proxy