# How do I point other websites to subdomains on my site without redirecting users?

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, subdomain, amazon-route53

Apologies in advance as I'm trying to do something and I don't know what it's called or the best way to describe it, but here's my best attempt:

I have a domain, let's say `aaa.com`, and that domain has a predefined subdomain for each customer that uses the system. Some examples of these subdomains would be: `bbb.aaa.com`, `ccc.aaa.com`, `ddd.aaa.com`, etc. Each customer also has their own website that they maintain separately (i.e., `bbb.com`, `ccc.com`, `ddd.com`, etc.).

What I'd like to do (but have no clue how to do) is point each of the customer's websites to their subdomain on my site without actually redirecting users.

For example, if a user goes to `bbb.com`, without them knowing it and without them being redirected, they would be viewing `bbb.aaa.com`. They would think that they are on `bbb.com` the whole time, not some subdomain of `aaa.com`. Similarly, if a user goes to `bbb.com/eee`, then I would like them to actually see the content on `bbb.aaa.com/eee` without being redirected.

I think I've seen this done before, so I'm assuming it's possible, but I'm not sure how this be done. I'm thinking that certain DNS records need to be added/modified on both the `aaa.com` side and for all the customer sites as well to make it happen, but I'm not really sure how.

I'm using AWS and Apache for everything, but the customers use a mixed bag of domain providers, etc. What I'm really looking for is a high-level overview of how it works with some specifics on how to implement it from any domain provider. For example, "Add an A record on the `aaa.com` side like this," etc. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing complicated on the DNS level : you point the domain you want your users to use to a server running a reverse proxy (either a dedicated product or web server like for instance Apache that has such functionality built in) and configure that reverse proxy to send requests for a particular URI space to a backend (rather than displaying local content ).

The devil is in the details though (from cookies to deep linking and cross site scripting protection on the back end sites and more.)

See for instance https://serverfault.com/a/561897