# Proxying a "port" application on relative url ("subdirectory") of same server in Apache 2.4?

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, port

I have seen [How to handle relative urls correctly with a reverse proxy](https://serverfault.com/questions/561892/how-to-handle-relative-urls-correctly-with-a-reverse-proxy) - however I have great troubles understanding this (and applying it to my problem), hope someone can help.

Let's say that I have Ubuntu 20.04 as a server OS on my server, `example.com`.

Then, I install https://github.com/hartwork/jawanndenn on the server, and run it - this application by default runs on port 8080; and I can confirm that it runs on the server itself, by running:

```
wget -O- http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

So far, so good. Now, what I would like, is that: instead of accessing `https://example.com:8080` to access this application, I'd like like to access `https://example.com/jaw` - where I'd usually call `/jaw` a "subdirectory", but it is maybe more accurately a relative URL. In other words, if I understand the terminology correctly, `https://example.com/jaw` would reverse proxy to `https://example.com:8080`.

So, I've tried doing this, within the `<VirtualHost *:443>` definition in my `.conf` file:

```
  <Location /jaw>
    Options -Multiviews -Indexes
    RewriteEngine On
    ProxyPass         http://127.0.0.1:8080
    ProxyPassReverse  http://127.0.0.1:8080
    SetOutputFilter proxy-html
    ProxyHTMLURLMap http://127.0.0.1:8080
  </Location>
  RewriteRule ^/jaw$ /jaw/ [R]
```

This works - in the sense that, the starting page of the application is loaded; but a whole ton of resources (.css, .js) cannot be loaded; opening the console in my browser, I can see a bunch of 404'd requests for:

```
https://example.com/static/3rdparty/jquery-3.5.1/jquery-3.5.1.min.js
https://example.com/static/3rdparty/roboto-20/css/roboto.css
...
```

So, my guess is, there are some .js files or similar, that simply want to load `/static/...` -> and if called from the "port" address, they'd map to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/static/...` and all would be fine; but now, since we're proxied:

- browser requests `https://example.com/jaw`
- Apache gets that, forwards it to `https://example.com:8080`, where the application listens
- Application sends back files (.js), that have links in the form `/static/...`
- Once those arrive back in the browser, they are interpreted as `https://example.com/static/...` - before being used as requests for the server, which then cannot find them

I've also tried getting rid of the entire `<Location>` snippet above, and just using this in the `<VirtualHost *:443>` node:

```
  ProxyPass /jaw/ http://127.0.0.1:6789/
  ProxyPassReverse /jaw/ http://127.0.0.1:6789/
```

Exactly the same happens as previously - first page gets loaded, all the other resources apparently refger to `/static/...` and they all 404.

Finally, I got rid of the above statements too, and used this:

```
  ProxyPass /jaw/  http://127.0.0.1:8080
  ProxyHTMLURLMap http://127.0.0.1:8080  /jaw
  <Location /jaw/>
    ProxyPassReverse /
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8080
    ProxyHTMLEnable On
    ProxyHTMLURLMap  /  /jaw/
  </Location>
```

This has the exact same behavior - first page loads, resources fail - except resources are now listed in browser console as:

```
https://example.com/jaw/static/3rdparty/jquery-3.5.1/jquery-3.5.1.min.js
https://example.com/jaw/static/3rdparty/roboto-20/css/roboto.css
...
```

... and they fail with 502 Proxy Error. So some rewrite happened, but something is not right still.

So my question is - how can I say to Apache, to proxy *everything* from the application on  127.0.0.1:8080, to something that appears as a "subdirectory" (relative URL? here `/jaw`)?

---

Edit: turns out, the 502 Proxy Error was due to:

```
AH00898: DNS lookup failure for: 127.0.0.1:6789static returned by /poll/static/js/html.js
```

... so clearly a slash is missing; so it ended up that this:

```
  ProxyPass /jaw/  http://127.0.0.1:8080/
  ProxyHTMLURLMap http://127.0.0.1:8080/  /jaw/
  <Location /jaw/>
    ProxyPassReverse /
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ProxyHTMLEnable On
    ProxyHTMLURLMap  /  /jaw/
  </Location>
```

... actually does work - for the most part (the `/static` resources); but then, there is a call to `/data` that does not get handled by this ... So it's still an open question (for me) how to proxy "*everything*"

Comment: Configure your backend server with the correct base url. That's much easier than forcing rewrites on the proxy.

Comment: Thanks @GeraldSchneider - that helped me to realize this application has a `--url-prefix` argument, and that ended up working for me ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Configure your backend server with the correct base url. That's much easier than forcing rewrites on the proxy.

The setting should be `JAWANNDENN_URL_PREFIX` . Just set it to `/jaw` and all URLs should be generated properly.

Your first example should then work, even without the ProxyHTMLURLMap and the OutputFilter.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using the `--url-prefix` to specify `JAWANNDENN_URL_PREFIX` to "`jaw`", and then just `ProxyPass/ProxyPassReverse /jaw/ http://127.0.0.1:8080/jaw/` works fine for the proxy.