# Reverse proxy in Apache + CentOS for HTTPS requests to PostgREST webserver

Tags: centos, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, https

I would like to make https requests to my postgREST webserver, which by design doesn't support https. I spend several days now I don't know any further...

**My setup**

- My server is running on CentOS 7.9.2009
- I have a website domain that uses Wordpress to serve my content in `home/myuser/public_html`
- I setup PostgREST 7.0.1 on my server which runs on port 3000
- I am running Apache/2.4.51 (cPanel)

**My Problem**

- The following request works just fine: `http://my-domain.com:3000/my_db_table`
- I would like to run the same request like: `https://my-domain.com/api/my_db_table`
- My Apache configuration is in an "includes" file, seems to be loaded (as errors occur when I put wrong syntax intentionally in this file) and it looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

    DocumentRoot /
    ServerName my-domain.com
    ServerAlias my-domain
    ErrorLog /home/myuser/public_html/api/error.log
    CustomLog /home/myuser/public_html/api/access.log combined

    SSLEngine on
    SSLUseStapling off
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/server.my-domain.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/server.my-domain.com.key


    <Location /api/ >
         ProxyPreserveHost On
         ProxyPass http://localhost:3000/
         ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000/
         RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"
         RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
   </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

- running `httpd -t` returns `Syntax OK`
- after my changes I run `sudo systemctl restart httpd`
- when I then try to do a request like `curl -i https://my-domain.com/api/my_db_table` I am redirected to the 404 page of my Wordpress website
- the `error.log` file of my apache config does not include any errors (it included errors for stapling which I resolved by adding the line `SSLUseStapling off` in my config)

I don't know what to do anymore. And because I don't have any error logs I even don't know how to start debugging it. I would be happy for any hint somebody could provide me.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to check:

1. Is SELinux running? If so is the SEBoolean `httpd_can_network_connect` set to 1?
2. Is `mod_proxy` installed?
3. Is anything on the non-proxied VirtualHost using the path `/api`? As in, would it block the calls to the `Location`? Better answer: [How to handle relative urls correctly with a reverse proxy](https://serverfault.com/questions/561892/how-to-handle-relative-urls-correctly-with-a-reverse-proxy)

Not an apache expert, but these sprang to mind!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I probably can rule out your suggestions. (1) No, it is disabled. (2) Running `httpd -M` shows me `proxy_module`, so it seems to be enabled. (3) I just created the `/api` directory in my wordpress environment in `home/myuser/public_html`, so there shouldn't be anything but this proxy

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the second point of the [answer given by shearn89](https://serverfault.com/a/1087916/946949), verify that the module `mod_proxy_http` is also installed (use `a2enmod proxy_http` to install it).