# apache reverse proxy not working

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, containers

I am using my apache container as a reverse-proxy and trying to access one of my VM services. It is working when I configure like,

```
ProxyPassMatch "^/(.*)$" "https://host1:443/$1"
ProxyPassReverse "^/(.*)$" "https://host1:443/$1"
```

With the above config I am able to access all the urls of https://host1:443/*. But When I want to access via an explicit worker like,

```
ProxyPassMatch "^/sample/(.*)$" "https://host1:443/$1"
ProxyPassReverse "^/sample/(.*)$" "https://host1:443/$1
```

It says "The requested URL /p/login/ was not found on this server." I tried many solutions and couldn't get to work.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> ProxyPassMatch "^/sample/(.*)$" "https://host1:443/$1"
> ```

When you only reverse proxy to host1 the URI paths starting with `/sample/` requests for `/p/login/`  shouldn't get forwarded. The requests for `/p/login/`  will be handled locally by your apache and won't reach host1.

When that path/URI is not present on your apache container that triggers the 404 - file not found error *""The requested URL /p/login/ was not found on this server."*

You usually get such an error because the HTML code on host1 links to the absolute path   `/p/login/` and a common misconception is the reverse proxy would change such a reference to `/sample/p/login/` by using the [`ProxyPassReverse`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse) directive. `ProxyPassReverse` doesn't do that. It only adjusts the URL in the `Location`, `Content-Location` and `URI` ***headers*** ; and not in the body/HTML code.

There are several things you can do to resolve that ; as detailed in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/561892/how-to-handle-relative-urls-correctly-with-a-reverse-proxy/561897#561897) (Note both your question and that answer are tagged with apache version `2.2` ; the other two answers in that question provide a  solution for current version `2.4`)