# Apache2 folders redirect to IPs

Tags: reverse-proxy, mod-rewrite, apache2, proxypass, lxc

I have installed Apache/2.4.56 (Debian), a noip URL and severals LXC containers. I need to access to the web apps inside the LXC containers:

```
example.com/app1 -> LXC container 1 (with Zend2)
example.com/app2 -> LXC container 2 (with Laravel 5)
example.com/app3 -> LXC container 3 (with Mattermost)
example.com/app4 -> LXC container 4 (with Plex)
example.com/app5 -> LXC container 5 (with Laravel 10)
example.com/app6 -> LXC container 5 (with Psono)
...
example.com/appN -> LXC container N
```

ip1: 10.0.3.101

ip2: 10.0.3.102

domain_url: http://example.com

1st approach:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass             "/app1"       "http://ip1"
    ProxyPassReverse      "/app1"       "http://ip1"
</VirtualHost>
```

If I enter to `example.com/app1` this send me to `example.com/auth/index/index` (I lost `app1`, this should be `example.com/app1/auth/index/index`). The ProxyPassReverse do not work?

2nd approach:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass             "/app1"       "http://ip1"
    ProxyPassReverse      "/app1"       "http://ip1"
    ProxyPassReverse      "/app1"       "/"
</VirtualHost>
```

This work great! but I need more LXC containers.

3rd approach:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass             "/app1"       "http://ip1"
    ProxyPassReverse      "/app1"       "http://ip1"
    ProxyPassReverse      "/app1"       "/"
    ProxyPass             "/app2"       "http://ip2"
    ProxyPassReverse      "/app2"       "http://ip2"
</VirtualHost>
```

`example.com/app1` -> OK

The buttons was wrong, so I made some changes:
The original action for the button was
`action="{{ route('login') }}"` and it resolve as `domain_url/login`
so I changed it to
`action="domain_url/app2/login">`
and the result was:
`example.com/app2` -> welcome page -> `example.com/app2/login` (login page) -> `example.com/app1/app2/login` WRONG

4rd approach:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass             "/app1"       "http://ip1"
    ProxyPassReverse      "/app1"       "http://ip1"
    ## WITH OUT THIS ##ProxyPassReverse      "/app1"        "/"
    ProxyPass             "/app2"       "http://ip2"
    ProxyPassReverse      "/app2"       "http://ip2"
</VirtualHost>
```

`example.com/app1` -> `example.com/auth/index/index` WRONG

The buttons was wrong, so I made some changes:
The original action for the button was
`action="{{ route('login') }}"` and it resolve as `domain_url/login`
so I changed it to
`action="domain_url/app2/login">`
and the result was:
`example.com/app2` -> welcome page -> `example.com/app2/login` (login page) -> ```example.com/app2/# with so many css, js and images lost.

I think I do not have to use ProxyPassReverse      "/app1"          "/"`, so I continue that path but always got` example.com/app1`->`example.com/auth/index/index```

This approach were:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass             "/app1"       "http://ip1"
    ProxyPassReverse      "/app1"       "http://ip1"
    ProxyPass             "/app2"       "http://ip2"
    ProxyPassReverse      "/app2"       "http://ip2"

    ##HERE THE ATTEMPS .. serverfault do not like to spam the same text over and over again xD
</VirtualHost>
```

The attemps:

```
Attempt #1

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^10\.0\.3\.101$
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ domain_url/app1/$1 [P,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^10\.0\.3\.102$
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ domain_url/app2/$1 [P,L]

Attempt #2

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{RESPONSE} ^.*app1.*
    RewriteRule ^/app1/(.*)$ /app1/$1 [P,L]
    
    RewriteCond %{RESPONSE} ^.*app2.*
    RewriteRule ^/app2/(.*)$ /app2/$1 [P,L]

Attempt #3

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/app1/
    RewriteRule ^/app1/(.*)$ domain_url/app1/$1 [P,L]
    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/app2/
    RewriteRule ^/app2/(.*)$ domain_url/app2/$1 [P,L]

Attempt #4

    ProxyHTMLEnable On
    ProxyHTMLExtended On

    ProxyHTMLURLMap http://ip1 domain_url/app1
    ProxyHTMLURLMap http://ip2 domain_url/app2

Attempt #5

    AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
    Substitute "s|http://10\.0\.3\.101|domain_url/app1|n"
    Substitute "s|http://10\.0\.3\.102|domain_url/app2|n"

Attempt #6

    RequestHeader edit Location ^http://10\.0\.3\.101(.*)$ domain_url/app1$1
    RequestHeader edit Location ^http://10\.0\.3\.101(.*)$ domain_url/app2$1
```

I need more ideas to test, someone can help me? please, any idea is welcome. I really appreciate your help. If this work, then I would like to configure HTTPS :D

P.S.: I prefer not to use ports, it is more formal to use `/app1`, etc.

Comment: Your first approach is correct. I bet that your app1 is redirecting the client. Use the CLI curl so that you can see the HTTP request and response including headers.

Comment: Indeed the first approach is correct, but that has problems when the application is deployed in the root of the backend server and uses absolute links to refer to  content and resources. Such links don't get "corrected" by a the `ProxyPassReverse` mapping (that corrects only  Location, Content-Location and URI **headers** and not response bodies). My answer in [this Q&A ](https://serverfault.com/questions/561892) is still mostly valid, despite being for apache 2.2 ,  the other answers provide direction on how to use `ProxyHTMLURLMap` which is more applicable for apache 2.4