Apache reverse proxy at /home-assistant path still loads resources from /

locally, home assistant is at http://192.168.1.125:8123
I need reverse proxy available at https://example.com/home-assistant
Virtual host https://example.com exsits and it should not be touched

My virtual host setup:
<VirtualHost *:443>
 
 
    ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyRequests off
        ProxyPass /home-assistant/api/websocket ws://192.168.1.125:8123/api/websocket
        ProxyPassReverse /home-assistant/api/websocket ws://192.168.1.125:8123/api/websocket
        ProxyPass /home-assistant http://192.168.1.125:8123
        ProxyPassReverse /home-assistant http://192.168.1.125:8123
 
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
        RewriteRule /home-assistant/(.*)  ws://192.168.1.125:8123/$1 [P,L]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket [NC]
        RewriteRule /home-assistant/(.*)  http://192.168.1.125:8123/$1 [P,L]
 
 
    SSLEngine On
 
 
        DocumentRoot /home/michal/sites/webmail
 
 
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>

But it does not work. When accessing https://example.com/home-assistant home assistant logo is loaded and I can see home assistant sitl tries to load its resources from example.com/ url, not example.com/home-assistant/ url, so it won't load.
How to make it working? I guess it will work if proxy is at top level '/', but not at '/home-assistant'
How to fix my rewrite rules to get all redirections made to example.com/home-assistant instead of example.com/?

Does this answer your question? Redirect, Change URLs or Redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Apache - Everything You Ever Wanted to Know About mod_rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask

I'm not sure if my use case is included there. I'm looking for solution for this specific case, your link is more general

The problem is typically that on its own mod_proxy doesn’t change the content it retrieves from the back-end server. It doesn’t change a reference to for example /css/style.css to /home-assistent/css/style.css - a long time ago I wrote a longer explanation here https://serverfault.com/a/561897/37681 for Apache 2.2 that is still mostly relevant and there is a second answer there as well for the current Apache 2.4 version

Excellent answer, because it seems that's the same case - reverse proxy at path, not top level url. It however seems to be more complicated than I expected.

Configure home assistant with the correct URL.

Go to Configuration > General Input your external and internal url in the appropriate boxes. Press save

https://community.home-assistant.io/t/base-url-deprecation-but-unclear-what-to-do-about-it/200377
It's always preferable to fix these issues by configuring the backend properly instead of having the reverse proxy rewrite the HTML on the fly.

I'm not sure if I really want to mess with backend configuration. Won't it break access from LAN via internal ip?

It most probably will. Just use the external address.

Not an solution in this case. I need to keep local access working
