ProxyPass response translate http to https
We have an external Apache server that proxies a https url to an internal http site
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName external.domain
    ServerAlias www.external.domain

    ProxyRequests Off
    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLProxyVerify none
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off


    ProxyPass    /    http://internal.domain/
    ProxyPassReverse    /    http://internal.domain/

    <various ssl cert stuff>
</VirtualHost>

However, the trouble is the internal site returns addresses for css / js with http
When viewing the site externally through the proxy, the response gives back link href or script src addresses that only have http in them, causing the external client to complains about mixed mode content for the css/js files (or just not load them)
So from the internal site you get links for:
        <link href="http://internal.domain/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="http://internal.domain/script.js"></script>

which get converted back through the proxy as:
        <link href="http://external.domain/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="http://external.domain/script.js"></script>

which only changes the domain back to the external one, but not the http back to https
This, then, causes browser errors such as:
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://external.domain/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://external.domain/stylesheet.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://external.domain/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://external.domain/script.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

I think Azure enterprise Application Proxy has an option to 'translate urls in application body' that does a similar thing, but I'm not sure how to achieve that in Apache
I've tried using these options to no avail:
Header edit Location ^http: https:
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Protocol "https"
But, I'm not sure it's the Headers I need to change, rather, I need a translation in the response
Is there a way to translate these links/refs from http to https in the initial response so the external client only sees https for this domain, and is none the wiser?
FOR clarity To be clear, this question is not the same as How to handle relative urls correctly with a reverse proxy, as there is no relative path issue, and this is dealing with the response from the server to the client, rather than how to handle incoming requests. The initial response back through the proxy not having translated http links back to https to the client and avoiding the client from blocking them due to mixed content.
If this question is still marked as duplicate/similar and you've come here looking for how to modify the response be aware that only answer Five-B from the other question answers this question.

My answer to https://serverfault.com/q/561892/37681  was written for Apache 2.2 and still is mostly relevant. Some of the others provide a solution specifically for the current Apache 2.4

@HBruijn I don't believe my question is similar enough. Mine is not to do with the path of links, rather the protocol in the response. The link paths don't need to change, and putting everything in a subfolder will not work. Extra proxy paths for subfolder will not work. Although your answer (5b) to that question does seem to work, I believe it's solving a different problem. I'll update the question to make it clear this is about the protocol in the original response and not the following calls to paths with css/js as the browser blocks those links before they come back to the server.

The protocol is part of the absolute links in the HTML code your backend server generates and how to rewrite that HTML code in the reverse proxy  is also explained in the answers there. There is no real difference between changing the path in http://example.com/foo to http://example.com/bar compared to  (only) rewriting  the protocol in the URL to   https://example.com/foo - Note that some web applications have settings to make it aware that it is exposed via a reverse proxy and then it can generate links with HTTPS even though it does not detect https on the backend server

Only 5B from your answer on the other question would work in this case as far as I can tell. I don't know if the questions should be linked or not, but ONLY 5B seemed relevant

To be clear, this question is not related to - yes it does. Check the outputfilter directives.

The proper way would however be to have the backend generate the correct URLs directly, instead of adding additional load by rewriting the whole content on the fly for every request.

@HBruijn I don't believe the questions are the same. There's nothing about the response needing to be modified in the other question, and there's nothing about relative links in this one. While one of your answers does seem to solve this issue for me, I can't see that any of the others in your answer do. If you could explain how a rewrite, different directory, more proxypass directives or an extra vhost with another proxypass directive could solve the outbound response containing http and not https then I'd be much happier with the questions being marked as similar to another question

@GeraldSchneider Yes, in an ideal world the internal site would also use https with it's own certificate, and would only use https. Sadly that's not always possible or under your control.

The concept of closing questions as duplicate is not that the questions are identical (although they can be) , rather the idea is that the answers  below the duplicate are also relevant to your problem.  https://serverfault.com/help/duplicates

@HBruijn I read that earlier and still don't quite see how it's a duplicate - only one small part of your answer remedies this issue. The rest of your answer and the other answers are completely irrelevant. I would also like to see if there are other solutions to the response translation other than your outputfilter section of the other question.

If you're confident that 5B of your answer to the other question is the only way to modify http to https in the response, then I'm happy to leave the question as a duplicate, so long as this question contains the reference to 5B of your answer, and it won't end up just being automatically redirected to the other question, or deleted, as that would then lose both this differing question and one answer to it

@HBruijn I don't want to argue the point too much, but the duplicate section of https://serverfault.com/help/closed-questions specifically mentions them being closed and marked as duplicate because This question has been asked before and already has an answer. Not because there's part of an answer for a different question that also happens to solve it
